# Passing multi-param function into a macro

Tags: c++, c, macros

Why does this not compile on VC 2005?

```
bool isTrue(bool, bool) { return true; }

void foo();

#define DO_IF(condition, ...) if (condition) foo(__VA_ARGS__);          

void run()
{
    DO_IF(isTrue(true, true)); // error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'constant'
}
```

Running this through the preprocessor alone outputs:

```
bool isTrue(bool, bool) { return true; }

void foo();



void run()
{
    if (isTrue(true  true)) foo();; 
}
```

Notice the missing comma in the penultimate line.

**Last Edit:**

LOL!

```
bool isTrue(bool, bool) { return true; }

void foo();

#define DO_IF(condition, ...) if (condition) { foo(__VA_ARGS__); }

void run()
{
    DO_IF(isTrue(true ,, true)); // ROTFL - This Compiles :)
}
```

Comment: Must be preprocessor bug. CPP shouldn't mess with macro parameter.

Comment: Seems like a preprocessor bug. 

From here:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177415(VS.80).aspx


"The C Standard specifies that at least one argument must be passed to the ellipsis, to ensure that the macro does not resolve to an expression with a trailing comma."


so instead of issues an error it mangles the input to (true  true).

Comment: Microsoft isn't correct. To eat trailing comma you just need to use ##__VAR_ARGS__, so you can provide no params at all, at least according to GCC docs: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html

Comment: Well, that may be the case in gcc but vc doesn't have this syntax

Comment: btw, this is definitely a C++ question as well. I'm not working with C, I haven't tested any of this with C. This happens in a CPP project and so I believe the C++ tag is fitting. I don't think C++ questions that might or might not pertain to the subset of the language shared by C should not be marked as C++. Such a policy would run the risk of missing C++ experts' input - ones that aren't necessarily interested in C.

Comment: Variadic macros aside, isn't this just the plain old problem associated with passing embedded commas to a macro? The preprocessor greedily assumes that the comma in your is meant for the macro. What if you protect the expression with extra parenthesis:

DO_IF((isTrue(true, true)));

Comment: @Cwan, that's not it. Passing an expression that contains commas works, and parens do not work on the above problem. By now I'm convinced it's a preprocessor bug... why else would it handle (true ,, true) "properly"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Macros with indefinite numbers of arguments don't exist in the 1990 C standard or the current C++ standard.  I think they were introduced in the 1999 C standard, and implementations were rather slow to adopt the changes from that standard.  They will be in the forthcoming C++ standard (which I think is likely to come out next year).

I haven't bothered to track C99 compliance in Visual Studio, mostly because the only things I use C for anymore require extreme portability, and I can't get that with C99 yet.  However, it's quite likely that VS 2005 lacked parts of C99 that VS2008 had.

Alternately, it could be that you were compiling the program as C++.  Check your compiler properties.

Comment: Variadic macros are supported in VC2005.
Though, it seems, with some implementation bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Run your code through CPP (C preprocessor) to see what substitutions CPP does for your macro.

You could do it either by invoking `cpp` or providing `-E` parameter to compiler (if you use `gcc`, of course).

Comment: +1 Most likely there is another macro that is messing up this macro.

Answer (score 1):

Various preprocessor implementations parse the commas greedily, treating them as separators for macro arguments.  Thus, CPP thinks that you're asking "DO_IF" to do a substitution with two parameters, "isTrue(true" and "true)".

Answer (score 0):

Your code compiles just fine in VS2008, if i change DO_IF to RETURN_IF. However, this should not change anything relevant for your error.

Edit: Still compiles without errors, even after your changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think that should work, except, shouldn't it be...

```
RETURN_IF(isTrue(b, !b));
```

and

```
RETURN_IF(isTrue(b,  b));
```

Comment: It's a toy example, it doesn't matter what b is (look at the function)

Comment: Er...OK? He had DO_IF and I replaced it with RETURN_IF in my reply.

Of course b doesn't matter! :)